# Populate text box with Json data

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Please see my below code,

Controller -

```
public ActionResult AmountOwed()
{
    int vehicleID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["VehicleID"].Value);
    var amountOwed = _PUSPERSContext.TblEOYPayments.Where(x => x.VehicleID == vehicleID).OrderByDescending(x => x.PaymentID).Take(1).Select(x => x.AmountOwed).ToList().FirstOrDefault();  
    return Json(amountOwed, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This gives me the value I want but I now want to display it in a textbox in a partial view (`_EOYPaymentsLayout.cshtml`) -

```
<div class='form-group'>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TblEOYPayment.AmountOwed, new { title = "Amount Owed" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TblEOYPayment.AmountOwed, new { title = "Amount Owed", @class = "form-control inputSizeMedium"})
</div>
```

I have have tried various things in my ajax code but I can never get the value into the view (this code is in the main view called `Payments`)  -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addEOYPayment').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "AmountOwed",
            datatype: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#TblEOYPayment_AmountOwed').html(data.amountOwed);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Would be grateful for some advice.  Thanks

Comment: What is $('#TblEOYPayment_AmountOwed')? Is it the text box you want to place the amount in?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Then `$('#TblEOYPayment_AmountOwed').val(data.amountOwed)` if the `data.amountOwed` is the correct value that should be filled in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return a json object, you can return a partial view

C#

```
    public ActionResult AmountOwed()
        {
            int vehicleID = 
            Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["VehicleID"].Value);

            var amountOwed = _PUSPERSContext.TblEOYPayments.Where(x => x.VehicleID == vehicleID).OrderByDescending(x => x.PaymentID).Take(1).Select(x => x.AmountOwed).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

            return PartialView("NameOfView.cshtml", amountOwed );
        }
```

js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#addEOYPayment').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",

                url: "AmountOwed",

                datatype: "Json",


                success: function (data) {
                    $('#TblEOYPayment_AmountOwed').html(data.responseText);
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

and your view may receive the type of thevariable amountOwed.

Answer (score 0):

You must double check your url. Please do include the controller name. For an instance: `URL: "\Home\AmountOwed\" + ID,`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

Finally got it working, it was just this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#addEOYPayment').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",

                    url: "/Home/AmountOwed",

                    datatype: "Json",


                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#TblEOYPayment_AmountOwed').val(data);                     

                    }

                });


            });
        });
```